Morlet wavelet convolution
I use a simple formula (without normalization) from Mike Cohen's "Analzying neural time series data" book.
\begin{align}
    \psi \left( t \right) &= e^{-\frac{t^2}{2 s^2}} \cdot e^{2 \pi \mathrm{i} f t}, \\
    s &= \frac{n_{\mathrm{cycles}}}{2 \pi f}, 
\end{align}
In another paper (https://www.eneuro.org/content/8/6/ENEURO.0202-21.2021), I found this formula of the Fourier transform of a Morlet wavelet.
\begin{align}
    \mathcal{F} (\psi  (a \omega)) = 2 e^{-\frac{(a\omega - \omega_0)^2}{2}} H( \omega) \label{cwt1},
\end{align}
where $H(\omega)$ is the Heaviside step function.
I wish to relate both formulas, in particular, I would like to understand the meaning of $\omega_0$, but I somehow don't see the connection. What is the time-domain formula of the Morlet wavelet they use in the paper?

To attack the problem, the two properties of the Fourier tranform come in handy

Scaling: ${\cal{F}}\{x(\frac{t}{a})\}(\xi) = |a|X(a\xi)$
Modulation: ${\cal{F}}\{x(t)e^{2\pi if_{0}t}\}(\xi) = X(\xi-f_{0})$
where $X(\xi) \triangleq {\cal{F}}\{x(t)\}$.

In addition to these, the Fourier transform of a Gaussian waveform is also a Gaussian, i.e.,
$$
{\cal{F}}\{e^{-\pi t^{2}}\}(\xi) = e^{-\pi\xi^{2}}
$$
Note that in the first exression $f$ is a constant. To avoid any confusion, you’d better denote it by $f_{0}$ where in that case $f_{0} = \omega_{0}/(2\pi)$.
